# Decoding Base64 Image and Displaying it in a gridview

Tags: asp.net, vb.net

I have a table called "Staff", in that table I have an entity with the name "ProfilePicture" containing an encoded Base64 Image string.

How can I decode the base64 image and display it in this gridview below?

```
<asp:GridView ID="staffgrid" runat="server" AutoGenerateColumns="False" DataKeyNames="Staff_ID" DataSourceID="staffdb">
        <Columns>
            <asp:BoundField DataField="Staff_ID" HeaderText="ID" ReadOnly="True" SortExpression="Staff_ID"></asp:BoundField>
            <asp:BoundField DataField="ProfilePicture" HeaderText="ProfilePicture" ReadOnly="true" SortExpression="ProfilePicture">
                <ItemStyle Width="100px"></ItemStyle>
            </asp:BoundField>
            <asp:BoundField DataField="Name" HeaderText="Name" SortExpression="Name"></asp:BoundField>
            <asp:BoundField DataField="Gender" HeaderText="gender" SortExpression="Gender"></asp:BoundField>
            <asp:BoundField DataField="Email" HeaderText="email" SortExpression="Email"></asp:BoundField>
            <asp:BoundField DataField="Password" HeaderText="password" SortExpression="Password"></asp:BoundField>
            <asp:CommandField ShowDeleteButton="True" ShowEditButton="True" ButtonType="Button" ShowHeader="True" HeaderText="Edit"></asp:CommandField>
            <asp:ImageField></asp:ImageField>
        </Columns>
    </asp:GridView>
    <asp:SqlDataSource runat="server" ID="staffdb" ConnectionString='<%$ ConnectionStrings:conStr %>' SelectCommand="SELECT [Staff_ID], [Name], [Email], [Password], [Gender], [ProfilePicture] FROM [Staff]"></asp:SqlDataSource>
```

I found a function on the internet that accepts a string and returns the image in a variable called `img`, but I can't figure out how to implement it.

```
Function Base64ToImage(ByVal base64string As String) As System.Drawing.Image
        'Setup image and get data stream together
        Dim img As System.Drawing.Image
        Dim MS As System.IO.MemoryStream = New System.IO.MemoryStream
        Dim b64 As String = base64string.Replace(" ", "+")
        Dim b() As Byte

        'Converts the base64 encoded msg to image data
        b = Convert.FromBase64String(b64)
        MS = New System.IO.MemoryStream(b)

        'creates image
        img = System.Drawing.Image.FromStream(MS)

        Return img
    End Function
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You don't need to convert the base64 string into a `System.Drawing.Image`. You can just display it in the GridView as a string.

```
<asp:TemplateField>
    <ItemTemplate>
        <img src="data:image/jpeg;base64,<%# Eval("ProfilePicture") %>" />
    </ItemTemplate>
</asp:TemplateField>
```

Comment: Worked like a charm. Thanks